# Correct way to call aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo version 2.7.2.

I just want to count occurrences by name matching by Hostname.

I don't want to use map/reduce. I want to do it through aggregate function.

Executing this query:

"Counting by name matching by Hostname"

```
cursor = self.coll.aggregate(
    {"$match": {"HOSTNAME": "XXYYX"}},
    {"$group": {"_id": {"Name": "$NAME"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
)
```

I got the following error:

```
line 46, in registerApps
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
TypeError: aggregate() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

This query is perfectly running over mongodb. But I don't know how to translate it properly to Pymongo.

Could you help me on this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate takes an *array* of commands as its parameter:

```
cursor = self.coll.aggregate(
          [
            { "$match": { "HOSTNAME": "XXYYX" }},
            { "$group": {
                "_id": {"Name": "$NAME"},
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
          ]
)
```

as described in the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html)